# Переменные Sass в create react app

Tags: reactjs

Как использовать переменные в компонентах. По разному менять пути? где-то будет `./../variables.scss`, а в другом месте `./../../../variables.scss`
http://prntscr.com/mkm63o
Есть способ почище?

Comment: [Adding a Sass Stylesheet in Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас `webpack`, то воспользуйтесь `resolve`, тогда вы сможете сделать пути к файлам абсолютными, а не относительными.

Почитать можно [тут](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

Comment: Сказано же `create-react-app`, зачем отвечать про вебпак?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach а там не вебпак?

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин Вебпак, но у вас нет доступа к его конфигурации

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach есть же eject. И тогда будет доступ к конфигурации.

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин Ну есть основной флоу, и есть кастомный. Я думаю что сначала нужно предложить решение для основного, а потом уже если не помогло строить костыли с кастомизацией сборки вебпака

Comment: Ну я предложил просто, вопрос был какие есть варианты. Мы же не знаем что человек хочет получить в итоге.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант №1**
Если все стили находятся в одной папке */styles* используйте файлы сборщики, чтобы импортировать их единожды:

*styles/index.scss*

```
@import "./constants.scss";
@import "./mixins.scss";
@import "./reset.scss";
```

*index.js*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./styles/index.scss";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

В таком случае Вам не понадобится импортировать переменные стилей в каждый файл отдельно.

**Вариант №2**
В случае если файлы стилей находятся в папке с каждым компонентом отдельно, и нужно импортировать общие переменные в них, можно использовать переменные окружения:

*.env*

```
SASS_PATH=src
```

*любой файл со стилями*

```
@import styles/variables.scss
```

Comment: А если в папке с компонентом лежит его scss файл, то как быть?

Comment: @stiv Добавил пример для такой структуры

Comment: Где добавить данную переменную? можете скинуть какое-нибудь руководство, сложно соориентироваться

Comment: @stiv на рутовом уровне проекта создаешь файл _.env_, и в него добавляешь переменную

Comment: Ошибка File to import not found or unreadable: styles/variables
1 создал файл, прописал пути http://prntscr.com/mle5w2
2 структура http://prntscr.com/mle6gu

Comment: @stiv Что Вы пытаетесь импортировать? У Вас же файл как называется? И про расширение файла не забывайте `@import 'styles/_variables.scss`